# Recover deleted files from FAT partition under Linux

Tags: linux, data-recovery, wine, testdisk

I need to recover deleted files from a FAT partition under Linux. I tried to do it with TestDisk and it was ok, but now I need to do it from a partition which has many bad sectors – and I found the bad sectors are only in files.

Those files are not deleted and all software I tried searched the entire partition, not only the free space which has all my deleted files.

I tried to use WinHex many times, but it does not work under Linux or Wine, so what should I try instead?

Answer (score 4):

Try the GPLv2 PhotoRec/TestDisk tools. It really helped me when I lost some important files.

[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)

**Note:**

PhotoRec attempts to recover files using magic bytes and file signatures, while TestDisk recovers files by looking at filesystem data. Therefor you should try TestDisk first, then PhotoRec.

Comment: An important note: PhotoRec attempts to recover files using magic bytes and file signatures, while TestDisk recovers files by looking at filesystem data. Therefor you should probably try TestDisk first, then PhotoRec.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer to your problem - you may want to focus more on a strategy for solving your problem, rather then looking for "some software" to get it back for you - particularly as you mentioned the word "Linux".

A possible strategy - if you have the disk space available on a clean disk might be to -
1.  Use GNU ddrescue to copy as much of the data as possible off the 
    failing drive to a new image/drive as possible.
2.  Make a copy of the new image/drive and try recovery on that.  If your attempt
    fails, make another copy and repeat...

On a clean copy, the first thing I would do is run a chkdsk (or fsck.vfat) to repair the filesystem, and then copy the data.  (I expect that the problems you are having will be corrected accessing the available data will be solved with an fsck)
If that fails I might try photorec or testdisk or other software. 
I would not use WINE - either I'd use a PC with Windows or a PC with Linux, but not a PC using Linux pretending to be Windows, as you really want to get as close to the filesystem as possible, and abstraction can only get in the way.